# Can you pull apart a string?

Tags: java, string

I'm storing a string in a database with a value such as "020734". I would like to be able to pull the string apart.

I have:

```
String values = "020734";
```

I need:

```
String values = "020734";
String value1 = "02";
String value2 = "07";
String value3 = "34";
```

Could you guys possibly point me in a general direction?

Comment: Yes, with my bare hands. Or robotic arms.

Comment: @BoltClock -- Robotic arms won't work if it's a null-Terminator string.

Comment: I removed the **`[android]`** tag, because it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: This is easily doable, but it's a bad idea.  Your database isn't normalized this way.  Better to store those values as separate columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erm, how about `value1 = values.substring(0, 2); value2 = values.substring(2,4)`...etc? That will get you two characters at a time from the string.

Comment: @shaheer: Obviously :) But sometimes an obvious answer is just what's needed.

Answer (score 3):

checkout [`String.substring`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29).

```
String values = "020734";
String value1 = values.substring(0, 2);
String value2 = values.substring(2, 4);
String value3 = values.substring(4, 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you always know the widths of the values you want then you could do the following:

```
String remainder = startString;
while (remainder.length() >= 2) {
    String newPart = remainder.substring(0, 2);
    // you can do something with each part
    remainder = remainder.substring(2, remainder.length());
}
```

This will break any string up into 2 character chunks.

You can view the `substring()` documentation here:

> http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29